# why i cannot click calendar in webview in android?

Tags: android, webview

Why I cannot click calendar in webview in android?
I have created an app in webview where there is a calendar section and when i click on it, it is not responding. But the same thing when I work on a url the calendar is responding.

Comment: is this a jquery calender?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one to enable JavaScript

```
webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.activity_stu_sec_webview);

   webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.activity_stu_sec_webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.loadUrl("http://www.x.com");
```

Comment: Hi Anil i need one more help from u.  when i open my web view app it shows a white page first and then shows the particular page, I don't want to see the white page when my net is slow. Instead I like to have an image along with a progressive circle and when there is a proper connection it should enter into the given url .